# Como habilitar e desabilitar um um input do tipo text após um valor selecionado no combobox

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee, jsp

**Meu jQuery**

```js
 < script >
   $(document).ready(function() {

     var tipo = $("#idTipoParticipante option:selected").text();


     if (tipo == 'Personagem') {

       $("#enable").click(function() {
         // habilitando o campo
         $('#personagem').attr("disabled", '');
         // retornando a cor padrao
         $('#personagem').css("background-color", "#FFF");

       });

     } else if (tipo == 'Tecnico') {
       // campo desabilitado
       $('#personagem').attr("disabled", true);
       // cor de fundo para o campo
       $('#personagem').css("background-color", "#cccccc");

     }

   }); < /script>
```

**Meu Select**

```html
<select class="form-control" name="idTipoParticipante" id="idTipoParticipante">
  <% List<TipoParticipante>listTipoParticipante = tipoParticipanteController.retornarListaTipoParticipante(); for (int i = 0; i
    < listTipoParticipante.size(); i++) { %>
      <option value="<%=listTipoParticipante.get(i).getIdTipoParticipante()%>">
        <%=listTipoParticipante.get(i).getDescricaoTipoParticipante()%>
      </option>

      <% } %>
</select>
```

**Meu input**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="personagem" name="personagem" placeholder="informe a personagem...">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banguela,

um exemplo mais simples do que você publicou seria:

```
<select class="form-control" name="idTipoParticipante" id="idTipoParticipante">
  <option value="0">Personagem</option>
  <option value="1">Tecnico</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="personagem" name="personagem" placeholder="informe a personagem...">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idTipoParticipante').change(function(){
        var tipo = $("#idTipoParticipante option:selected").text();
        if (tipo == 'Personagem') {
            $('#personagem').attr('disabled', false);
        }else if (tipo == 'Tecnico') {
            $('#personagem').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Aqui está [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jm4ctv0m/3/)

Basicamente o que você deve fazer além do ponto que você já foi é: adicionar uma ação para o evento change do `$('idTipoParticipante')`. Assim toda vez que o seu idTipoParticipante for modificado você poderá comparar os valores novamente.

Comment: Ok, vou implementar agora amigo!

Comment: Rubico, fantâstico! show de bolas... funcionou perfeitamente. Preciso estudar mais JavaScript ou jQuery. são tecnologias bastante interessante no munto de desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 1):

Faça a verificação no evento `change` no campo select:

```js
$('#idTipoParticipante').on('change', function() {
  var tipo = $(this).find('option:selected').text().trim();
  if(tipo == 'Personagem') {
   $('#personagem').prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else if(tipo == 'Tecnico') {
   $('#personagem').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="personagem" name="personagem" placeholder="informe a personagem...">
<select id="idTipoParticipante">
  <option></option>
  <option value="">
    Personagem
  </option>
  <option value="">
    Tecnico
  </option>  
</select>
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/v8q4uuz1/4/) no jsfiddle

Comment: Miguel, fantâstico! show de bolas... funcionou perfeitamente. Preciso estudar mais JavaScript ou jQuery. são tecnologias bastante interessante no munto de desenvolvimento.

Comment: ainda bem que ajudou @Banguela. Yap para browser-based apps (que corram no navegador), é do melhor